# Fetch Error : [TypeError: Network request failed]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql, fetch-api

I'm using GraphQL in React Native, but it doesn't have much to do with the fact that I'm using RN. When I want to make a request to an endpoint that I want, it throws me the error [TypeError: Network request failed], but only in the function that I want, I tried with some examples, and it responds correctly

**I leave 3 functions and the output in the terminal:**

```
const fetchh = async () => {
await fetch('https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/ensdomains/ens', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: `
    query ($name: String!)
        {
          domains(first: 75, where: {name_contains: $name, resolvedAddress_not: null, name_ends_with: ".eth"}) {    
            name    
          }
        }
    `,
    variables: {
      name: 'asd',
    },
  }),
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result, 'RESULTADO'))
  .catch(err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err), 'ERROR FETCH1'));
};
```

====

```
  const fetch2 = async () => {
fetch('https://www.learnwithjason.dev/graphql', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: `
      query GetLearnWithJasonEpisodes($now: DateTime!) {
        allEpisode(limit: 10, sort: {date: ASC}, where: {date: {gte: $now}}) {
          date
          title
          guest {
            name
            twitter
          }
          description
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      now: new Date().toISOString(),
    },
  }),
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result, 'FETCH 2'));
};
```

======

```
const fetch3 = async () => {
fetch('https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/ensdomains/ens', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    query: `query ($address: ID!)
  { 
      accounts(where: {id: $address}, first: 1000) {
          registrations {
              domain {                      
                name
                subdomains {
                  name
                }
              }
              expiryDate
          }   
      } 
  }`,
    variables: {
      address: '0x9844'.toLowerCase(),
    },
  }),
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(err => console.log(err, 'ERROR FETCH 3'));
};
```

```
LOG [TypeError: Network request failed] ERROR FETCH 3
LOG {"line":25338,"column":33,"sourceURL":"localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.welookapp&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true"} ERROR FETCH1

LOG {"data": {"allEpisode": [[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]]}} FETCH 2
```

The error FETCH 1 and FETCH 3 are the same except for FETCH1 I put JSON.stringify in the .catchIt can also be seen that FETCH 2 brought the results correctly, do you know what could be happening?

Comment: Are you sure that the api you are trying to access actually exists?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yes, the endpoint in web is working